# Draw Life Wheel

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want make a life wheel similar to this:

[image]

[image]

I have tried to make one using tikz; however I got stuck in

1. I want name like "Career" to be aligned with the perimeter of the circle
2. I will want the math (scale) to be correct for the inner shape (circle) from 1 to 10. In my code I am using things like `\angle*1:\mybf+.1012cm*\mcf`. I want the value of `\mybf+.1012cm*\mcf` to be 1, 2, 3, etc.
3. Show the value (number) 1, 2, 3, etc

Please see the one I made. I used many `\def` and defined variables that I am sure an expert person will do simpler and easier.

[image]

Finally, here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{forestgreen}{RGB}{60,127,50}
\definecolor{mahogany}{RGB}{169,52,72}
\definecolor{insightly}{RGB}{255,74,0}
\definecolor{minbelow}{RGB}{167,116,16}

\def\mybf{.55cm}
\def\radiusf{\mybf}
\def\mcf{.55cm} 

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) circle (8cm);
\node[draw, circle, inner sep=.2mm] (a) at (0,0) {};

\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {360, 315, ..., 45}
{
 \draw[thin, gray!40] (a) -- (\x:\radiusf+212);
}
\def\shi{255};
\draw (360:\radiusf+\shi) node {Health};
\draw (315:\radiusf+\shi) node {Spritual};
\draw (270:\radiusf+\shi) node {Career};
\draw (225:\radiusf+\shi) node {Financial};
\draw (180:\radiusf+\shi) node {Friends \& Family};
\draw (135:\radiusf+\shi) node {Personal Growth};
\draw (90:\radiusf+\shi) node {Romance};
\draw (45:\radiusf+\shi) node {Entetainment};
\def\angle{360/8};

\draw[mahogany]   (\mybf+.1090cm*\mcf,0) -- (\angle*1:\mybf+.1012cm*\mcf) -- (\angle*2:0.235cm*\mcf) -- (\angle*3:\mybf+.0898cm*\mcf) -- (\angle*4:\mybf+.0918cm*\mcf)-- (\angle*5:\mybf+.0906cm*\mcf)-- (\angle*6:\mybf+.0963cm*\mcf) -- (\angle*7:\mybf+.1018cm*\mcf) -- (\angle*8:\mybf+.1025cm*\mcf) -- (\mybf+.1090cm*\mcf,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a very interesting challenge, here a puzzle to make the first graph, I created a function called `\lifeweel`, the first parameter indicates the levels, the second the grid, the third indicates the quantity of features, the fourth parameter is a construction with the names of each character with the specific value.

UPDATE: Using scope to allow draw more than one graph, create a second smart objet code, called `\lifeweelS` means that you can convert `\lifeweel` objet adding "S" this creates another type of lifeweel. Opcodes `\lifeweel{levels}{grid}{number of features}{feature_name/quantity}[anchor angle][numbers direction in degrees][relative position](ID);`

RESULT:

[image]

MWE?:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
% By J. Leon V. Share as Beerware philosophy
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, arrows.meta,calc,shadows.blur,shadings}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set font to serif family

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        % Environment Cfg
        font=\Large,
        scale=1,
        % Styles
        Grid/.style={
            loosely dotted,
            line width=1.5pt,
            color=black
            },
        Separator/.style={
            thick,
            color=black!50
        },
        Border/.style={
            line width=1pt,
            color=red!60
        },
        Border2/.style={
            line width=2pt,
            color=red!60
        },
        Fill/.style={
            fill=black,
            opacity=0.1
        }
    ]
% lifeweel from many codes arround TEX.SE
%Variables: 1:levels, 2:grid 3:number of features 4: Feature_name/quantity
% 5: anchor aling 6: numbers position 7:Relative position 8:ID
\def\lifeweel#1#2#3#4[#5][#6](#7)(#8){%
\begin{scope}[shift={(#7)}] 
%Decoration
    \foreach \n  in {0,#2,...,#1}{
        \draw[fill=black, opacity=0.1] (0,0) circle [radius=\n];}
%Drawing the grid and numbers.
    \foreach \n  in {0,#2,...,#1}{
        \draw[Grid] (0,0) circle [radius=\n];
        \node[anchor=#5] (A) at (#6:\n+0.2){\n};}

%Drawing features separations.
    \foreach \m [count=\i] in {0,1,...,#3}{
        \draw[Separator] (0,0) -- (360/#3*\i: #1);}

%Drawing the border
\draw[Border] (0,0) circle [radius=#1];

%Drawing the names
    \foreach \o/\p [count=\j] in {#4}{
        \pgfmathparse{int(360/#3*\j)} 
        \ifthenelse{ \pgfmathresult >180}
        {% True
        \path[%Reverse
            decoration={
                raise = -0.8ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center,
                reverse path
            },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/#3*\j:#1+0.7) arc (360/#3*\j:360/#3*(\j-1):#1+0.7);%\path
        }
        {%False
        \path[%Normal
            decoration={
                raise = -0.8ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center
                },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/#3*\j:#1+0.7) arc (360/#3*\j:360/#3*(\j-1):#1+0.7); %Path
        }
    \draw[Border2]
    (360/#3*\j:\p) coordinate (#8a\j) 
    arc (360/#3*\j:360/#3*(\j-1):\p) coordinate (#8b\j);
    \draw[fill=red, opacity=0.2]
    (0,0) -- (360/#3*\j:\p) arc (360/#3*\j:360/#3*(\j-1):\p);

}
\pgfmathparse{int(#3+1)} % Principle of uroboro
\coordinate (#8b\pgfmathresult) at (#8b1);
 \foreach \o/\p [count=\i, evaluate=\i as \x using int(\i+1)] in {#4}{%Close the perimete
    \draw[Border2] (#8a\i) -- (#8b\x);}
\end{scope}
}

%Variables: 1:levels, 2:grid 3:number of features 4: Feature_name/quantity
% 5: anchor aling 6: numbers position 7:Relative position 8: ID
\def\lifeweelS#1#2#3#4[#5][#6](#7)(#8){%
\begin{scope}[shift={(#7)}] 
%Drawing the  numbers.
    \foreach \n  [count=\m]  in {0,#2,...,#1}{
        \node[anchor=#5] (A) at (#6:\n+0.2){\n};
    }
%Drawing the  grid
    \foreach \n  in {0,#2,...,#1}{
        \foreach [count=\i, evaluate=\i as \x using int(\i+1)]\m in {0,1,...,#3}{
        \draw[Grid](360/#3*\i:\n) -- (360/#3*\x:\n);
        \draw[Fill](360/#3*\i:\n) -- (0,0) -- (360/#3*\x:\n);
        }
    }   
%Drawing features separations.
    \foreach \m [count=\i] in {0,1,...,#3}{
        \draw[Separator] (0,0) -- (360/#3*\i: #1);}

%Drawing the border
\draw[fill=black, opacity=0.1] (0,0) circle [radius=#1];
\draw[Border] (0,0) circle [radius=#1];

%Drawing the names
    \foreach \o/\p [count=\j from 0] in {#4}{
        \pgfmathparse{int(360/#3*\j)}
        \ifthenelse{\pgfmathresult =90 \OR \pgfmathresult =270}
            {%True
            \draw (360/#3*\j:#1+0.7) node [anchor=center]{\huge\o};
            }
            {%false
            \ifthenelse{\pgfmathresult <90 \OR \pgfmathresult >270}
                {% True
                \draw (360/#3*\j:#1+0.7) node [anchor=west]{\huge\o};
                }
                {%False
                \draw (360/#3*\j:#1+0.7) node [anchor=east]{\huge\o};
                }
            }
    \coordinate (#8c\j) at (360/#3*\j:\p);
}

\coordinate (#8c#3) at (#8c0);
 \foreach \o/\p [count=\i from 0, evaluate=\i as \x using int(\i+1)] in {#4}{%Close the perimete
    \draw[Border2] (#8c\i) -- (#8c\x);
    \draw[fill=red, opacity=.2] (#8c\i) --(0,0) -- (#8c\x);
    }
\end{scope}
}


% This function draws the lifeweel
%\lifeweel{levels}{grid}{number of features}{feature_name/quantity}[anchor angle][numbers direction in degrees][relative position](ID);
\lifeweel{10}{2}{8}{
        Money/5,
        Entertainment/4,
        Romance/7,
        Presonal Growth/9,
        Friends {\&} Family/3,
        Financial/5,
        Spiritual/7,
        Health/5
        }[45][180](0,0)(1);

\lifeweel{10}{1}{5}{
        Money/5,
        Entertainment/3,
        Romance/8,
        Presonal Growth/6,
        Friends {\&} Family/8
        }[-90][0](25,0)(2);

\lifeweelS{10}{2}{8}{
        Money/5,
        Entertainment/4,
        Romance/7,
        Presonal Growth/9,
        Friends {\&} Family/3,
        Financial/5,
        Spiritual/7,
        Health/5
        }[45][180](0,-25)(3);

\lifeweelS{10}{1}{5}{
        Money/5,
        Entertainment/3,
        Romance/8,
        Presonal Growth/6,
        Friends {\&} Family/8
        }[-90][0](25,-25)(4);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PSD: The code allows you to reach those extremes, although it is a little dark (not so easy to read), I think you can play with all options, of course reach these extremes is just for fun and create a useful tikz framework.

Answer (score 9):

I have a "minimal damage proposal" as I do not understand why you use `landscape` and `article` instead of `standalone`. And note that dimensionless lengths are interpreted as `pt`. I used anchors to put the stuff close to the circle.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{forestgreen}{RGB}{60,127,50}
\definecolor{mahogany}{RGB}{169,52,72}
\definecolor{insightly}{RGB}{255,74,0}
\definecolor{minbelow}{RGB}{167,116,16}

\def\mybf{.55cm}
\def\radiusf{8cm}
\def\mcf{.55cm} 

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) circle (\radiusf);
\node[draw, circle, inner sep=.2mm] (a) at (0,0) {};

\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {360, 315, ..., 45}
{
 \draw[thin, gray!40] (a) -- (\x:\radiusf);
}
\foreach \X in {1,...,9} {
\draw[dashed,gray] (0,0) circle ({\radiusf*\X/10}); 
\node[above left] at (180:{\radiusf*\X/10}){\X}; 
}
\def\shi{2pt};
\draw (360:\radiusf+\shi) node[anchor=west] {Health};
\draw (315:\radiusf+\shi) node[anchor=north west] {Spritual};
\draw (270:\radiusf+\shi) node[anchor=north] {Career};
\draw (225:\radiusf+\shi) node[anchor=north east] {Financial};
\draw (180:\radiusf+\shi) node[anchor=east] {Friends \& Family};
\draw (135:\radiusf+\shi) node[anchor=south east] {Personal Growth};
\draw (90:\radiusf+\shi) node[anchor=south] {Romance};
\draw (45:\radiusf+\shi) node[anchor=south west] {Entertainment};
\def\angle{360/8};

\draw[mahogany,thick] 
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {1,2,1,3,2,1,2,3}
{\ifnum\Y>1
--
\else
\pgfextra{\xdef\Xstart{\X}}
\fi
({\angle*\Y}:{\radiusf*\X/10}) arc({\angle*\Y}:{\angle*(\Y+1)}:{\radiusf*\X/10})
 } 
--(\angle:{\radiusf*\Xstart/10});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: added numbers and simplified the mahagony curve.

Comment: Nice. However, I want this line
\draw[mahogany]   (\mybf+.1090cm*\mcf,0) -- (\angle*1:\mybf+.1012cm*\mcf) -- (\angle*2:0.235cm*\mcf) -- (\angle*3:\mybf+.0898cm*\mcf) -- (\angle*4:\mybf+.0918cm*\mcf)-- (\angle*5:\mybf+.0906cm*\mcf)-- (\angle*6:\mybf+.0963cm*\mcf) -- (\angle*7:\mybf+.1018cm*\mcf) -- (\angle*8:\mybf+.1025cm*\mcf) -- (\mybf+.1090cm*\mcf,0);

to be easier i.e., 1, 2, ....10 not \mybf+.0963cm*\mcf

Comment: @OOzyPal Sorry for not having read your question carefully. I added an update. You only need to specify the amplitudes.