# Wheel calendar template

Tags: calendar

Does anybody know if there is such a thing as this for LaTeX?
I have used my google-fu but alas come up empty handed, and my latex-fu is not up to scruff.
[image: plandisc.com]

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435053/drawing-circular-crop-calendar-in-tikz could help

Comment: What's your input? Dates? Week numbers? If you're willing to specify whether an event overlaps with another and maybe specify how text should be rotated, I could see this working with TikZ.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys! Well, the data would vary, very much like the example. I could give tikz a go, but I'm a spoiled GUI user, my head hurts when I try tikz :-)