# custom colour wheel

Tags: tikz-pgf

I saw the "draw wheel code" in post:

[Draw Life Wheel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434489/draw-life-wheel?rq=1)

and now I want to change something:

1. 8 different colour for each segment and gradient fill.
2. insert 3 icons in each segment.
3. insert one image in the center of the wheel.

This is the changed code

```
    % arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
% By J. Leon V. Share as Beerware philosophy
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, arrows.meta,calc,shadows.blur,shadings}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set font to serif family

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        % Environment Cfg
        font=\Large,
        scale=1,
        % Styles
        Grid/.style={
            loosely dotted,
            line width=1.5pt,
            color=black
            },
        Separator/.style={
            thick,
            color=black!50
        },
        Border/.style={
            line width=1pt,
            color=red!60
        },
        Border2/.style={
            line width=2pt,
            color=red!60
        },
        Fill/.style={
            fill=black,
            opacity=0.1
        }
    ]
% lifeweel from many codes arround TEX.SE
%Variables: 1:levels, 2:grid 3:number of features 4: Feature_name/quantity
% 5: anchor aling 6: numbers position 7:Relative position 8:ID
\def\lifeweel#1#2#3#4[#5][#6](#7)(#8){%
\begin{scope}[shift={(#7)}] 
%Decoration
    \foreach \n  in {0,#2,...,#1}{
        \draw[fill=black, opacity=0.1] (0,0) circle [radius=\n];}
%Drawing the grid and numbers.
    \foreach \n  in {0,#2,...,#1}{
        \draw[Grid] (0,0) circle [radius=\n];
        \node[anchor=#5] (A) at (#6:\n+0.2){\n};}

%Drawing features separations.
    \foreach \m [count=\i] in {0,1,...,#3}{
        \draw[Separator] (0,0) -- (360/#3*\i: #1);}

%Drawing the border
\draw[Border] (0,0) circle [radius=#1];

%Drawing the names
    \foreach \o/\p [count=\j] in {#4}{
        \pgfmathparse{int(360/#3*\j)} 
        \ifthenelse{ \pgfmathresult >180}
        {% True
        \path[%Reverse
            decoration={
                raise = -0.8ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center,
                reverse path
            },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/#3*\j:#1+0.7) arc (360/#3*\j:360/#3*(\j-1):#1+0.7);%\path
        }
        {%False
        \path[%Normal
            decoration={
                raise = -0.8ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center
                },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/#3*\j:#1+0.7) arc (360/#3*\j:360/#3*(\j-1):#1+0.7); %Path
        }
    \draw[Border2]
    (360/#3*\j:\p) coordinate (#8a\j) 
    arc (360/#3*\j:360/#3*(\j-1):\p) coordinate (#8b\j);
    \draw[fill=red, opacity=0.2]
    (0,0) -- (360/#3*\j:\p) arc (360/#3*\j:360/#3*(\j-1):\p);

}
\pgfmathparse{int(#3+1)} % Principle of uroboro
\coordinate (#8b\pgfmathresult) at (#8b1);
 \foreach \o/\p [count=\i, evaluate=\i as \x using int(\i+1)] in {#4}{%Close the perimete
    \draw[Border2] (#8a\i) -- (#8b\x);}
\end{scope}
}

%Variables: 1:levels, 2:grid 3:number of features 4: Feature_name/quantity
% 5: anchor aling 6: numbers position 7:Relative position 8: ID
\def\lifeweelS#1#2#3#4[#5][#6](#7)(#8){%
\begin{scope}[shift={(#7)}] 
%Drawing the  numbers.
    \foreach \n  [count=\m]  in {0,#2,...,#1}{
        \node[anchor=#5] (A) at (#6:\n+0.2){\n};
    }
%Drawing the  grid
    \foreach \n  in {0,#2,...,#1}{
      \foreach [count=\i, evaluate=\i as \x using int(\i+1)]\m in {0,1,...,#3}{
        \draw[Grid](360/#3*\i:\n) -- (360/#3*\x:\n);
      \draw[Fill](360/#3*\i:\n) -- (0,0) -- (360/#3*\x:\n);
        }
  }   
%Drawing features separations.
    \foreach \m [count=\i] in {0,1,...,#3}{
        \draw[Separator] (0,0) -- (360/#3*\i: #1);}

%Drawing the border
\draw[fill=black, opacity=0.1] (0,0) circle [radius=#1];
\draw[Border] (0,0) circle [radius=#1];

%Drawing the names
    \foreach \o/\p [count=\j from 0] in {#4}{
        \pgfmathparse{int(360/#3*\j)}
        \ifthenelse{\pgfmathresult =90 \OR \pgfmathresult =270}
            {%True
            \draw (360/#3*\j:#1+0.7) node [anchor=center]{\huge\o};
            }
            {%false
            \ifthenelse{\pgfmathresult <90 \OR \pgfmathresult >270}
                {% True
                \draw (360/#3*\j:#1+0.7) node [anchor=west]{\huge\o};
                }
                {%False
                \draw (360/#3*\j:#1+0.7) node [anchor=east]{\huge\o};
                }
            }
    \coordinate (#8c\j) at (360/#3*\j:\p);
}

\coordinate (#8c#3) at (#8c0);
 \foreach \o/\p [count=\i from 0, evaluate=\i as \x using int(\i+1)] in {#4}{%Close the perimete
    \draw[Border2] (#8c\i) -- (#8c\x);
    \draw[fill=red, opacity=.2] (#8c\i) --(0,0) -- (#8c\x);
    }
\end{scope}
}


% This function draws the lifeweel
%\lifeweel{levels}{grid}{number of features}{feature_name/quantity}[anchor angle][numbers direction in degrees][relative position](ID);
\lifeweel{10}{10}{8}{
        Money/10,
        Entertainment/10,
        Romance/10,
        Presonal Growth/10,
        Friends {\&} Family/10,
        Financial/10,
        Spiritual/10,
        Health/10
        }[45][180](0,0)(1);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Different background color and gradient fill are from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247900/31034).

Center imaging is from my recently [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473488/31034), using `pullquote` environment.

And the whole code is as follow:

```
    \documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tikz,pgf,xparse}
    \usepackage{pgfmath}
    \usepackage{xifthen}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, arrows.meta,calc,shadows.blur,shadings}
    \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set font to serif family
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FOR COLOR TRANSITION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\vardonut}[1]{
    \newcounter{num}
    \foreach \content/\size/\colour in {#1}
        \stepcounter{num};
    \foreach \content/\size/\colour [count=\i] in {#1}{
        \draw[white,very thick,top color=\colour!50!black, bottom color=\colour, shading angle={-90+360/\thenum/2+(\i-1)*360/\thenum}] 
        ({2*cos((\i-1)*360/\thenum)},{2*sin((\i-1)*360/\thenum)}) arc[radius = 2, start angle={(\i-1)*360/\thenum}, delta angle=360/\thenum] --
        ({(2+\size)*cos(\i*360/\thenum)},{(2+\size)*sin(\i*360/\thenum)}) arc[radius = {2+\size}, start angle={\i*360/\thenum}, delta angle=-360/\thenum] -- 
        cycle;
      %  \node[white,font=\large] at ({(\i-1)*360/\thenum+360/\thenum/2}:{\size/2+2}) {\content};
    }
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%END OF COLOR TRANSITION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            % Environment Cfg
            font=\Large,
            scale=1,
            % Styles
            Grid/.style={
                loosely dotted,
                line width=1.5pt,
                color=black
                },
            Separator/.style={
                thick,
                color=black!50
            },
            Border/.style={
                line width=1pt,
                color=red!60
            },
            Border2/.style={
                line width=2pt,
                color=red!60
            },
            Fill/.style={
                fill=black,
                opacity=0.1
            }
        ]
    % lifeweel from many codes arround TEX.SE
    %Variables: 1:levels, 2:grid 3:number of features 4: Feature_name/quantity
    % 5: anchor aling 6: numbers position 7:Relative position 8:ID
    \def\lifeweel#1#2#3#4[#5][#6](#7)(#8){%
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#7)}] 
    %Decoration
        \foreach \n  in {0,#2,...,#1}{
            \draw[fill=black, opacity=0.1] (0,0) circle [radius=\n];}
    %Drawing the grid and numbers.
        \foreach \n  in {0,#2,...,#1}{
            \draw[Grid] (0,0) circle [radius=\n];
            \node[anchor=#5] (A) at (#6:\n+0.2){\n};}

    %Drawing features separations.
        \foreach \m [count=\i] in {0,1,...,#3}{
            \draw[Separator] (0,0) -- (360/#3*\i: #1);}

    %Drawing the border
    \draw[Border] (0,0) circle [radius=#1];

    %Drawing the names
        \foreach \o/\p [count=\j] in {#4}{
            \pgfmathparse{int(360/#3*\j)} 
            \ifthenelse{ \pgfmathresult >180}
            {% True
            \path[%Reverse
                decoration={
                    raise = -0.8ex,
                    text  along path,
                    text = {|\huge|\o},
                    text align = center,
                    reverse path
                },
                decorate
            ]
            (360/#3*\j:#1+0.7) arc (360/#3*\j:360/#3*(\j-1):#1+0.7);%\path
            }
            {%False
            \path[%Normal
                decoration={
                    raise = -0.8ex,
                    text  along path,
                    text = {|\huge|\o},
                    text align = center
                    },
                decorate
            ]
            (360/#3*\j:#1+0.7) arc (360/#3*\j:360/#3*(\j-1):#1+0.7); %Path
            }
        \draw[Border2]
        (360/#3*\j:\p) coordinate (#8a\j) 
        arc (360/#3*\j:360/#3*(\j-1):\p) coordinate (#8b\j);
        \draw[fill=red, opacity=0.2]
        (0,0) -- (360/#3*\j:\p) arc (360/#3*\j:360/#3*(\j-1):\p);

    }
    \pgfmathparse{int(#3+1)} % Principle of uroboro
    \coordinate (#8b\pgfmathresult) at (#8b1);
     \foreach \o/\p [count=\i, evaluate=\i as \x using int(\i+1)] in {#4}{%Close the perimete
        \draw[Border2] (#8a\i) -- (#8b\x);}
    \end{scope}
    }

    %Variables: 1:levels, 2:grid 3:number of features 4: Feature_name/quantity
    % 5: anchor aling 6: numbers position 7:Relative position 8: ID
    \def\lifeweelS#1#2#3#4[#5][#6](#7)(#8){%
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#7)}] 
    %Drawing the  numbers.
        \foreach \n  [count=\m]  in {0,#2,...,#1}{
            \node[anchor=#5] (A) at (#6:\n+0.2){\n};
        }
    %Drawing the  grid
        \foreach \n  in {0,#2,...,#1}{
          \foreach [count=\i, evaluate=\i as \x using int(\i+1)]\m in {0,1,...,#3}{
            \draw[Grid](360/#3*\i:\n) -- (360/#3*\x:\n);
          \draw[Fill](360/#3*\i:\n) -- (0,0) -- (360/#3*\x:\n);
            }
      }   
    %Drawing features separations.
        \foreach \m [count=\i] in {0,1,...,#3}{
            \draw[Separator] (0,0) -- (360/#3*\i: #1);}

    %Drawing the border
    \draw[fill=black, opacity=0.1] (0,0) circle [radius=#1];
    \draw[Border] (0,0) circle [radius=#1];

    %Drawing the names
        \foreach \o/\p [count=\j from 0] in {#4}{
            \pgfmathparse{int(360/#3*\j)}
            \ifthenelse{\pgfmathresult =90 \OR \pgfmathresult =270}
                {%True
                \draw (360/#3*\j:#1+0.7) node [anchor=center]{\huge\o};
                }
                {%false
                \ifthenelse{\pgfmathresult <90 \OR \pgfmathresult >270}
                    {% True
                    \draw (360/#3*\j:#1+0.7) node [anchor=west]{\huge\o};
                    }
                    {%False
                    \draw (360/#3*\j:#1+0.7) node [anchor=east]{\huge\o};
                    }
                }
        \coordinate (#8c\j) at (360/#3*\j:\p);
    }

    \coordinate (#8c#3) at (#8c0);
     \foreach \o/\p [count=\i from 0, evaluate=\i as \x using int(\i+1)] in {#4}{%Close the perimete
        \draw[Border2] (#8c\i) -- (#8c\x);
        \draw[fill=red, opacity=.2] (#8c\i) --(0,0) -- (#8c\x);
        }
    \end{scope}
    }


    % This function draws the lifeweel
    %\lifeweel{levels}{grid}{number of features}{feature_name/quantity}[anchor angle][numbers direction in degrees][relative position](ID);
    \lifeweel{10}{10}{8}{
            Money/10,
            Entertainment/10,
            Romance/10,
            Presonal Growth/10,
            Friends {\&} Family/10,
            Financial/10,
            Spiritual/10,
            Health/10
            }[45][180](0,0)(1);

            \ColourTransitionCircle[inner=0,outer=8,angle=40]{red,yellow,blue,blue,green}
    \draw (0,0)circle (8);

    \tikzset{
            d1/.pic={
                \foreach \t in {10,55,100,145,190,235,280,325} {
                    \draw[fill, red,thick] (\t:9) circle (0.5cm);
               }
            }
        }
        \tikzset{
            d2/.pic={
                 \foreach \t in {22.5,67.5,112.5,157.5,202.5,247.5,292.5,337.5} {
                    \draw[fill, blue,thick] (\t:9) circle (0.5cm);
                }
            }
        }
        \tikzset{
            d3/.pic={
              \foreach \t in {35,80,125,170,215,260,305,350} {
                    \draw[fill,orange,thick] (\t:9) circle (0.5cm);
                }
            }
        }
        \tikzset{
        d4/.pic={\node[circle,draw,minimum size=5cm,
               text=white,
               path picture={
                   \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
                       \includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a}
                   };
               }]{};}
        }

    \pic at (0,0) {d1};
    \pic at (0,0) {d2};
    \pic at (0,0) {d3};
    \pic at (0,0) {d4};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

and the output is:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Just for fun. An attempt to "reinvent the wheel". The purpose of this exercise is not to answer the question, i.e. I think the tick should go to [ferahfeza's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473792/121799). The purpose here is to

1. eliminate redundancies. E.g. the number of features is already determined by the number of entries of the feature list.
2. making things more Ti*k*Zy. Instead of defining a command with 8 arguments it might be more appropriate to focus on the relevant data only, and to store all the parameters in pgf keys. This has also the advantage that, if someone else is to customize this, something like `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}` may be easier to interpret than `#1`, say. And it is easy to add more possibilities without changing the syntax of the command.
3. remove unnecessary packages. There is no need to load `xifthen`, Ti*k*Z allows on to distinguish all the cases with built in features. (And `\usepackage{pgfmath}` does not have to be loaded.)

This answer cooks the command down to

```
\LifeWeel[radius=9,outer image radius=0.8,%
    colors={"red","blue","magenta","purple","orange","green"}
    ]{"example-image-duck","example-image-a","example-image-b","example-image-c"}{%
            Money/10,
            Entertainment/10,
            Romance/10,
            Personal Growth/10,
            Friends {\&} Family/10,
            Financial/10,
            Spiritual/10,
            Health/10}
```

where the first argument is the list of the graphics that is to be included (the first one is the one in the middle), and the second argument is the list of features. Everything else can be controlled by options that are passed as zeroth argument.

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,shadings}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set font to serif family
% smuggling from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470979/121799
\newcounter{smuggle}
\DeclareRobustCommand\smuggleone[1]{%
  \stepcounter{smuggle}%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname#1%
  \aftergroup\let\aftergroup#1\expandafter\aftergroup\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\smuggle[2][1]{%
  \smuggleone{#2}%
  \ifnum#1>1
    \aftergroup\smuggle\aftergroup[\expandafter\aftergroup\the\numexpr#1-1\aftergroup]\aftergroup#2%
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        % Environment Cfg
        font=\Large,
        scale=1,
        % Styles
    ]
\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,
radius/.initial=10,
outer image radius/.initial=1,
inner image radius/.initial=2,
outer image parameters/.initial={width=2.5cm},
inner image parameters/.initial={width=5cm},
Separator/.style={thick, color=black!50},
Border/.style={line width=1pt,color=red!60,shading=color wheel},
colors/.initial={}
}    
% lifeweel from many codes arround TEX.SE
%Variables: 1:images, 2:image 3:number of features 4: Feature_name/quantity
% 5: anchor aling 6: numbers position 7:Relative position 8:ID
\newcommand\LifeWeel[3][]{%
\def\imglst{{#2}}
\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,#1}
\edef\LstColors{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/colors}}
\edef\NumColors{0}
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 1] in \LstColors
{\edef\NumColors{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumColors}}
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {#2}
{\edef\NumImages{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumImages}}
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {#3}
{\edef\NumFeatures{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumFeatures}}
%Drawing the border
\draw[life wheel/Border] (0,0) circle [radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}];
%Drawing features separations.
\ifnum\NumColors>1
\foreach \m [count=\i] in {1,...,\NumFeatures}{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myi}{mod(\i-1,\NumColors)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\LstColors}[\myi]}
\draw[life wheel/Separator,top color=\mycolor!75!black,
bottom color=\mycolor,shading angle={-90+(360/\NumFeatures)*(\i-0.5)}] (0,0) -- (360/\NumFeatures*\i:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius})
arc({(360/\NumFeatures)*\i}:{(360/\NumFeatures)*(\i-1)}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius})
-- cycle;}
\else
\foreach \m [count=\i] in {0,1,...,\NumFeatures}{
\draw[life wheel/Separator] (0,0) -- (360/\NumFeatures*\i:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius});}
\fi

%Drawing the names
    \foreach \o/\p [count=\j] in {#3}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{ifthenelse(sin(360/\NumFeatures*\j)<0,-1,1)} 
        \ifnum\myint<0% True
        \path[%Reverse
            decoration={
                raise = -0.8ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center,
                reverse path
            },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/\NumFeatures*\j:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7) arc (360/\NumFeatures*\j:360/\NumFeatures*(\j-1):\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7);%\path
        \else%False
        \path[%Normal
            decoration={
                raise = -0.8ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center
                },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/\NumFeatures*\j:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7) arc (360/\NumFeatures*\j:360/\NumFeatures*(\j-1):\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7); %Path
        \fi
    \foreach \X in {1,...,\NumImages}
    {\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{360/\NumFeatures*\j+((1-2*\X)/(2*\NumImages))*360/\NumFeatures}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\imgname}{\imglst[\X]}
    \begin{scope}
     \clip (\tmp:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life
     wheel/radius}-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}}) 
     circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}];
     \node[rotate={\tmp-\myint*90}] at 
     (\tmp:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}})   
     {\edef\temp{\noexpand\includegraphics[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image parameters}]{\imgname}}
     \temp};    
    \end{scope}
    }
}
\begin{scope}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\imgname}{\imglst[0]}
    \clip (0,0) circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/inner image radius}];
    \node at (0,0)
    {\edef\temp{\noexpand\includegraphics[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/inner image parameters}]{\imgname}}
     \temp}; 
\end{scope}
}


% This function draws the lifeweel
%\LifeWeel{figures}{list of features in the form feature_name/quantity}
\LifeWeel[radius=9,outer image radius=0.8,%
colors={"red","blue","magenta","purple","orange","green"}
]{"example-image-duck","example-image-a","example-image-b","example-image-c"}{%
        Money/10,
        Entertainment/10,
        Romance/10,
        Personal Growth/10,
        Friends {\&} Family/10,
        Financial/10,
        Spiritual/10,
        Health/10}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you leave the color list out, i.e. do

```
\LifeWeel[radius=9,outer image radius=0.8,%
%colors={"red","blue","magenta","purple","orange","green"}
]{"example-image-duck","example-image-a","example-image-b","example-image-c"}{%
        Money/10,
        Entertainment/10,
        Romance/10,
        Personal Growth/10,
        Friends {\&} Family/10,
        Financial/10,
        Spiritual/10,
        Health/10}
```

what I originally thought the question was about

[image]

Comment: I thought u would insert the mighty `falcon` instead of these beautiful ducks ;)

Comment: @Raaja Good point. (I focused on making the thingy more easy to customize in my update. The sheer number of arguments drove me almost crazy.) (The problem with inserting nicer images is that either one has to blow up the code because one draws them with Ti*k*Z, or include graphics that not everyone has on their machines.)

Comment: I will try to plug in Falcons in the morn (CET `;-)`). Lets see how far I go :D

Comment: @Raaja As long no duck nor marmot gets harmed, I'm fine with it. ;-)

Comment: we will see :D I will post it in the chat (if I succeed ;D)

Comment: +1: 100k are getting close :)

Comment: @marmot, thank you very much. The ducks are beautiful :-)

Comment: Wow, it's beautiful wheel :) :). Thanks you @marmot and ferahfeza.  In this code of Marmot, how can i change 4 image: ""example-image-a","example-image-b","example-image-c","example-image-duck" with image in folder: ex \includegraphics{/Image/Wheelimage/wheel01.jpg}

Comment: @tisaigon E.g. `\LifeWeel[radius=9,outer image radius=0.8]{"/Image/Wheelimage/wheel01.jpg","/Image/Wheelimage/wheel02.jpg","/Image/Wheelimage/wheel03.jpg","/Image/Wheelimage/wheel04.jpg"}{...` One can rewrite the code to take an arbitrary number of pictures or generalize it even further.

Comment: @marmot thank, it works well. Original code includes 8 segments. Now I have life wheel concept with only 7 segments. Ex: one segment "Friends & Family" is bigger than 6 other segment. How can edit your above code for only 7 segments? Thanks

Comment: @tisaigon If you only want to have 7 equally big segments, just drop feature of the list. If you want to have different sizes, one has to modify the code. (The original code does not support this either.) However, in this case you may be better off with a pie chart like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247878/121799). One can customize the above to give that, but if you want to have this, please accept  ferahfeza's nice answer and ask a new question with all the requirements. You will get an answer, and asking questions is free.

Comment: @marmot thanks for your remind. I have accepted ferahfeza's answer. One small question: How can i edit wheel size: smaller scale? thanks

Comment: @tisaigon just choose radius=7 or something of that sort.

Comment: Thank @marmot. Please tell me how i can edit/modify color of wheel, thanks.

Comment: @marmot: thanks. first i removed "shading=color wheel" and add \ColourTransitionCircle[inner=0,outer=8,angle=40]{red,yellow,blue,blue,green} (like code's ferahfeza. but fail: all color of wheel become "white".  Please help.

Comment: @tisaigon I added the possibility to add a list of colors that will me run through (and if the list is too short, it will cycle through). If you do not specify the list, you get the original answer. However, I would kindly ask you to make additional requests in form of a new question.

Comment: @marmot, thank for help. i will post other new topic when i have question. In your new update, all color can change, but i see "gradient" 8 colour that display not like your original code. Do i need create new ask in forum for it? Thanks

Comment: @tisaigon Sorry, I do not understand. Do you mean that the color list is not as in the original post?

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault. Done.