# copy and scale one figure (wheel)

Tags: tikz-pgf

i want continues in previous post: [custom colour wheel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473774/custom-colour-wheel)

This Minimal Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,landscape,left=1.0cm,right=0.3cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,shadings}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set font to serif family
% smuggling from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470979/121799
\newcounter{smuggle}
\DeclareRobustCommand\smuggleone[1]{%
  \stepcounter{smuggle}%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname#1%
  \aftergroup\let\aftergroup#1\expandafter\aftergroup\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\smuggle[2][1]{%
  \smuggleone{#2}%
  \ifnum#1>1
    \aftergroup\smuggle\aftergroup[\expandafter\aftergroup\the\numexpr#1-1\aftergroup]\aftergroup#2%
  \fi
}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        % Environment Cfg
        font=\Large,
        scale=1,
        % Styles
    ]
\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,
radius/.initial=10,
outer image radius/.initial=0.5,
inner image radius/.initial=1,
outer image parameters/.initial={width=1.25cm},
inner image parameters/.initial={width=2.5cm},
Separator/.style={thick, color=black!50},
Border/.style={line width=1pt,color=red!60,shading=color wheel},
colors/.initial={}
}    
% lifeweel from many codes arround TEX.SE
%Variables: 1:images, 2:image 3:number of features 4: Feature_name/quantity
% 5: anchor aling 6: numbers position 7:Relative position 8:ID
\newcommand\LifeWeel[3][]{%
\def\imglst{{#2}}
\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,#1}
\edef\LstColors{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/colors}}
\edef\NumColors{0}
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 1] in \LstColors
{\edef\NumColors{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumColors}}
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {#2}
{\edef\NumImages{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumImages}}
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {#3}
{\edef\NumFeatures{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumFeatures}}
%Drawing the border
\draw[life wheel/Border] (0,0) circle [radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}];
%Drawing features separations.
\ifnum\NumColors>1
\foreach \m [count=\i] in {1,...,\NumFeatures}{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myi}{mod(\i-1,\NumColors)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\LstColors}[\myi]}
\draw[life wheel/Separator,top color=\mycolor!75!black,
bottom color=\mycolor,shading angle={-90+(360/\NumFeatures)*(\i-0.5)}] (0,0) -- (360/\NumFeatures*\i:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius})
arc({(360/\NumFeatures)*\i}:{(360/\NumFeatures)*(\i-1)}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius})
-- cycle;}
\else
\foreach \m [count=\i] in {0,1,...,\NumFeatures}{
\draw[life wheel/Separator] (0,0) -- (360/\NumFeatures*\i:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius});}
\fi

%Drawing the names
    \foreach \o/\p [count=\j] in {#3}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{ifthenelse(sin(360/\NumFeatures*\j)<0,-1,1)} 
        \ifnum\myint<0% True
        \path[%Reverse
            decoration={
                raise = -0.4ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center,
                reverse path
            },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/\NumFeatures*\j:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7) arc (360/\NumFeatures*\j:360/\NumFeatures*(\j-1):\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7);%\path
        \else%False
        \path[%Normal
            decoration={
                raise = -0.8ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center
                },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/\NumFeatures*\j:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.35) arc (360/\NumFeatures*\j:360/\NumFeatures*(\j-1):\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.35); %Path
        \fi
    \foreach \X in {1,...,\NumImages}
    {\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{360/\NumFeatures*\j+((1-2*\X)/(2*\NumImages))*360/\NumFeatures}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\imgname}{\imglst[\X]}
    \begin{scope}
     \clip (\tmp:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life
     wheel/radius}-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}}) 
     circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}];
     \node[rotate={\tmp-\myint*90}] at 
     (\tmp:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}})   
     {\edef\temp{\noexpand\includegraphics[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image parameters}]{\imgname}}
     \temp};    
    \end{scope}
    }
}
\begin{scope}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\imgname}{\imglst[0]}
    \clip (0,0) circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/inner image radius}];
    \node at (0,0)
    {\edef\temp{\noexpand\includegraphics[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/inner image parameters}]{\imgname}}
     \temp}; 
\end{scope}
}


% This function draws the lifeweel
%\LifeWeel{figures}{list of features in the form feature_name/quantity}
\LifeWeel[radius=5,outer image radius=0.4,%
colors={"red","blue","magenta","purple","orange","green"}
]{"example-image-a","example-image-a","example-image-b","example-image-c"}{%
        A/10,
        B/10,
        C/10,
        D/10,
        E/10,
        F/10,
        G/10,
        H/10}
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How can i clone and scale this wheel (bigger/smaller) and put copy in same page with some other image/text?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I wrote [my life wheel answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473798/121799), which you are using here but not linking to, I did that precisely in order to [remove the vast number of arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473774/custom-colour-wheel#comment1195142_473798) in favor of pgf keys. The only things that were not moved to the pgf keys were the image list and the texts. Other than that there is nothing that prevents you from using the `\LifeWheel` command with a minimal number of arguments, you can set all the defaults in the pgf keys.

To simplify matter even further,

1. I moved the list of images also to the pgf keys, and
2. made the `decorations.text` susceptible to the scale of the ambient `tikzpicture` since otherwise, as [noted by Joule V](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481073/121799), these texts do not get scaled properly.

With these changes, drawing a simple life wheel boils down to

```
\tikz{\LifeWeel{A/10,B/10,C/10,D/10,E/10,F/10,G/10,H/10}}
```

but I stress that before that all you needed to do is to add the list of figures, so the command was not much longer. With the above-mentioned changes, now it scales properly, i.e. you could do something like

```
\tikz[scale=0.5,transform shape]{\LifeWeel{A/10,B/10,C/10,D/10,E/10,F/10,G/10,H/10}}
```

Setting the defaults is (and was) as simple as saying

```
\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,
radius=5,outer image radius=0.4,%
colors={"red","blue","magenta","purple","orange","green"},
img list={"example-image-a","example-image-a","example-image-b","example-image-c"}}
```

Let me mention that, while there is nothing wrong with a `\scalebox`, I am not a big fan of it, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480300/how-can-i-nest-multiple-groups-of-nodes-with-the-tikz-package/480362?noredirect=1#comment1215433_480362) for more details. Of course, if you are absolutely sure you do not want to access the nodes later, you will be fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,landscape,left=1.0cm,right=0.3cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,shadings}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set font to serif family
% smuggling from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470979/121799
\newcounter{smuggle}
\DeclareRobustCommand\smuggleone[1]{%
  \stepcounter{smuggle}%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname#1%
  \aftergroup\let\aftergroup#1\expandafter\aftergroup\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\smuggle[2][1]{%
  \smuggleone{#2}%
  \ifnum#1>1
    \aftergroup\smuggle\aftergroup[\expandafter\aftergroup\the\numexpr#1-1\aftergroup]\aftergroup#2%
  \fi
}

\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,
radius/.initial=10,
outer image radius/.initial=0.5,
inner image radius/.initial=1,
outer image parameters/.initial={width=1.25cm},
inner image parameters/.initial={width=2.5cm},
Separator/.style={thick, color=black!50},
Border/.style={line width=1pt,color=red!60,shading=color wheel},
colors/.initial={},
img list/.initial={"example-image-a","example-image-a","example-image-b","example-image-c"}
}    
% lifeweel from many codes arround TEX.SE
%Variables: 1:images, 2:image 3:number of features 4: Feature_name/quantity
% 5: anchor aling 6: numbers position 7:Relative position 8:ID
\newcommand\LifeWeel[2][]{%\pgfkeys{/tikz/life wheel/img list=#2}%\def\imglst{{#2}}
\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,#1}
\pgfgettransformentries{\mysfx}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\mysfy}{\tmp}{\tmp}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myfsx}{\mysfx*24} % decoration text 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myfsy}{\mysfy*24} % font scaling
\edef\imglst{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/img list}}
\edef\LstColors{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/colors}}
\edef\NumColors{0}
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 1] in \LstColors
{\edef\NumColors{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumColors}}
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in \imglst
{\edef\NumImages{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumImages}}
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {#2}
{\edef\NumFeatures{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumFeatures}}
%Drawing the border
\draw[life wheel/Border] (0,0) circle [radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}];
%Drawing features separations.
\ifnum\NumColors>1
\foreach \m [count=\i] in {1,...,\NumFeatures}{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myi}{mod(\i-1,\NumColors)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\LstColors}[\myi]}
\draw[life wheel/Separator,top color=\mycolor!75!black,
bottom color=\mycolor,shading angle={-90+(360/\NumFeatures)*(\i-0.5)}] (0,0) -- (360/\NumFeatures*\i:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius})
arc({(360/\NumFeatures)*\i}:{(360/\NumFeatures)*(\i-1)}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius})
-- cycle;}
\else
\foreach \m [count=\i] in {0,1,...,\NumFeatures}{
\draw[life wheel/Separator] (0,0) -- (360/\NumFeatures*\i:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius});}
\fi
%Drawing the names
    \foreach \o/\p [count=\j] in {#2}{%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{ifthenelse(sin(360/\NumFeatures*\j)<0,-1,1)} 
        \ifnum\myint<0% True
        \path[%Reverse
            decoration={
                raise = -0.4ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\fontsize{\myfsy}{\myfsx}\selectfont|\o},
                text align = center,
                reverse path
            },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/\NumFeatures*\j:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7) arc (360/\NumFeatures*\j:360/\NumFeatures*(\j-1):\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7);%\path
        \else%False
        \path[%Normal
            decoration={
                raise = -0.8ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\fontsize{\myfsy}{\myfsx}\selectfont|\o},
                text align = center
                },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/\NumFeatures*\j:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.35) arc (360/\NumFeatures*\j:360/\NumFeatures*(\j-1):\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.35); %Path
        \fi
    \foreach \X in {1,...,\NumImages}
    {\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{360/\NumFeatures*\j+((1-2*\X)/(2*\NumImages))*360/\NumFeatures}         
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\imgname}{{\imglst}[\X]}
    \begin{scope}
     \clip (\tmp:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life
     wheel/radius}-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}}) 
     circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}];
     \node[rotate={\tmp-\myint*90}] at 
     (\tmp:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}})   
     {\edef\temp{\noexpand\includegraphics[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image parameters}]{\imgname}}
     \temp};    
    \end{scope}
    }
}
\begin{scope}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\imgname}{{\imglst}[0]}
    \clip (0,0) circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/inner image radius}];
    \node at (0,0)
    {\edef\temp{\noexpand\includegraphics[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/inner image parameters}]{\imgname}}
     \temp}; 
\end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
% this defines all your default parameters. Of course, you can change them at any time.
\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,
radius=5,outer image radius=0.4,%
colors={"red","blue","magenta","purple","orange","green"},
img list={"example-image-a","example-image-a","example-image-b","example-image-c"}}

% drawing the actual life wheel is as simple as
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\Large,scale=1]
\LifeWeel{A/10,B/10,C/10,D/10,E/10,F/10,G/10,H/10}
\end{tikzpicture}%
~\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\Large,scale=0.5,transform shape]
\LifeWeel{A/10,B/10,C/10,D/10,E/10,F/10,G/10,H/10}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank so much. in my above post is linked to old topic that use your code. thanks

Comment: @latexforti Yes, but this worked with none of the `\LifeWheel` versions. This is because these texts are passed to `decorations.text`. So what you can do is to say `\LifeWeel{{|\small| AAA AAA}/10,B/10,C/10,D/10,E/10,F/10,G/10,H/10},` where the notation `|\small|` is the one that is appropriate to `decorations.text`. Probably `\small` is too small and you want to do something like `\LifeWeel{{|\fontsize{16}{16}\selectfont| AAA AAA}/10,B/10,C/10,D/10,E/10,F/10,G/10,H/10},`.

Answer (score 5):

Like this – when I changed `scale=1` to `scale=0.5`? (I changed to `a4paper` so to have more space for big figures.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,left=1.0cm,right=0.3cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,shadings}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set font to serif family
% smuggling from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470979/121799
\newcounter{smuggle}
\DeclareRobustCommand\smuggleone[1]{%
  \stepcounter{smuggle}%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname#1%
  \aftergroup\let\aftergroup#1\expandafter\aftergroup\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\smuggle[2][1]{%
  \smuggleone{#2}%
  \ifnum#1>1
    \aftergroup\smuggle\aftergroup[\expandafter\aftergroup\the\numexpr#1-1\aftergroup]\aftergroup#2%
  \fi
}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        % Environment Cfg
        font=\Large,
        scale=0.5,
        % Styles
    ]
\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,
radius/.initial=10,
outer image radius/.initial=0.5,
inner image radius/.initial=1,
outer image parameters/.initial={width=1.25cm},
inner image parameters/.initial={width=2.5cm},
Separator/.style={thick, color=black!50},
Border/.style={line width=1pt,color=red!60,shading=color wheel},
colors/.initial={}
}    
% lifeweel from many codes arround TEX.SE
%Variables: 1:images, 2:image 3:number of features 4: Feature_name/quantity
% 5: anchor aling 6: numbers position 7:Relative position 8:ID
\newcommand\LifeWeel[3][]{%
\def\imglst{{#2}}
\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,#1}
\edef\LstColors{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/colors}}
\edef\NumColors{0}
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 1] in \LstColors
{\edef\NumColors{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumColors}}
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {#2}
{\edef\NumImages{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumImages}}
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {#3}
{\edef\NumFeatures{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumFeatures}}
%Drawing the border
\draw[life wheel/Border] (0,0) circle [radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}];
%Drawing features separations.
\ifnum\NumColors>1
\foreach \m [count=\i] in {1,...,\NumFeatures}{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myi}{mod(\i-1,\NumColors)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\LstColors}[\myi]}
\draw[life wheel/Separator,top color=\mycolor!75!black,
bottom color=\mycolor,shading angle={-90+(360/\NumFeatures)*(\i-0.5)}] (0,0) -- (360/\NumFeatures*\i:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius})
arc({(360/\NumFeatures)*\i}:{(360/\NumFeatures)*(\i-1)}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius})
-- cycle;}
\else
\foreach \m [count=\i] in {0,1,...,\NumFeatures}{
\draw[life wheel/Separator] (0,0) -- (360/\NumFeatures*\i:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius});}
\fi

%Drawing the names
    \foreach \o/\p [count=\j] in {#3}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{ifthenelse(sin(360/\NumFeatures*\j)<0,-1,1)} 
        \ifnum\myint<0% True
        \path[%Reverse
            decoration={
                raise = -0.4ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center,
                reverse path
            },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/\NumFeatures*\j:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7) arc (360/\NumFeatures*\j:360/\NumFeatures*(\j-1):\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7);%\path
        \else%False
        \path[%Normal
            decoration={
                raise = -0.8ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center
                },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/\NumFeatures*\j:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.35) arc (360/\NumFeatures*\j:360/\NumFeatures*(\j-1):\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.35); %Path
        \fi
    \foreach \X in {1,...,\NumImages}
    {\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{360/\NumFeatures*\j+((1-2*\X)/(2*\NumImages))*360/\NumFeatures}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\imgname}{\imglst[\X]}
    \begin{scope}
     \clip (\tmp:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life
     wheel/radius}-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}}) 
     circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}];
     \node[rotate={\tmp-\myint*90}] at 
     (\tmp:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}})   
     {\edef\temp{\noexpand\includegraphics[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image parameters}]{\imgname}}
     \temp};    
    \end{scope}
    }
}
\begin{scope}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\imgname}{\imglst[0]}
    \clip (0,0) circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/inner image radius}];
    \node at (0,0)
    {\edef\temp{\noexpand\includegraphics[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/inner image parameters}]{\imgname}}
     \temp}; 
\end{scope}
}


% This function draws the lifeweel
%\LifeWeel{figures}{list of features in the form feature_name/quantity}
\LifeWeel[radius=5,outer image radius=0.4,%
colors={"red","blue","magenta","purple","orange","green"}
]{"example-image-a","example-image-a","example-image-b","example-image-c"}{%
        A/10,
        B/10,
        C/10,
        D/10,
        E/10,
        F/10,
        G/10,
        H/10}
        \end{tikzpicture} \begin{tikzpicture}[
        % Environment Cfg
        font=\Large,
        scale=1,
        % Styles
    ]
\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,
radius/.initial=10,
outer image radius/.initial=0.5,
inner image radius/.initial=1,
outer image parameters/.initial={width=1.25cm},
inner image parameters/.initial={width=2.5cm},
Separator/.style={thick, color=black!50},
Border/.style={line width=1pt,color=red!60,shading=color wheel},
colors/.initial={}
}    
% lifeweel from many codes arround TEX.SE
%Variables: 1:images, 2:image 3:number of features 4: Feature_name/quantity
% 5: anchor aling 6: numbers position 7:Relative position 8:ID
\newcommand\LifeWeel[3][]{%
\def\imglst{{#2}}
\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,#1}
\edef\LstColors{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/colors}}
\edef\NumColors{0}
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 1] in \LstColors
{\edef\NumColors{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumColors}}
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {#2}
{\edef\NumImages{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumImages}}
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {#3}
{\edef\NumFeatures{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumFeatures}}
%Drawing the border
\draw[life wheel/Border] (0,0) circle [radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}];
%Drawing features separations.
\ifnum\NumColors>1
\foreach \m [count=\i] in {1,...,\NumFeatures}{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myi}{mod(\i-1,\NumColors)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\LstColors}[\myi]}
\draw[life wheel/Separator,top color=\mycolor!75!black,
bottom color=\mycolor,shading angle={-90+(360/\NumFeatures)*(\i-0.5)}] (0,0) -- (360/\NumFeatures*\i:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius})
arc({(360/\NumFeatures)*\i}:{(360/\NumFeatures)*(\i-1)}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius})
-- cycle;}
\else
\foreach \m [count=\i] in {0,1,...,\NumFeatures}{
\draw[life wheel/Separator] (0,0) -- (360/\NumFeatures*\i:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius});}
\fi

%Drawing the names
    \foreach \o/\p [count=\j] in {#3}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{ifthenelse(sin(360/\NumFeatures*\j)<0,-1,1)} 
        \ifnum\myint<0% True
        \path[%Reverse
            decoration={
                raise = -0.4ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center,
                reverse path
            },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/\NumFeatures*\j:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7) arc (360/\NumFeatures*\j:360/\NumFeatures*(\j-1):\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7);%\path
        \else%False
        \path[%Normal
            decoration={
                raise = -0.8ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center
                },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/\NumFeatures*\j:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.35) arc (360/\NumFeatures*\j:360/\NumFeatures*(\j-1):\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.35); %Path
        \fi
    \foreach \X in {1,...,\NumImages}
    {\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{360/\NumFeatures*\j+((1-2*\X)/(2*\NumImages))*360/\NumFeatures}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\imgname}{\imglst[\X]}
    \begin{scope}
     \clip (\tmp:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life
     wheel/radius}-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}}) 
     circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}];
     \node[rotate={\tmp-\myint*90}] at 
     (\tmp:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}})   
     {\edef\temp{\noexpand\includegraphics[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image parameters}]{\imgname}}
     \temp};    
    \end{scope}
    }
}
\begin{scope}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\imgname}{\imglst[0]}
    \clip (0,0) circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/inner image radius}];
    \node at (0,0)
    {\edef\temp{\noexpand\includegraphics[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/inner image parameters}]{\imgname}}
     \temp}; 
\end{scope}
}


% This function draws the lifeweel
%\LifeWeel{figures}{list of features in the form feature_name/quantity}
\LifeWeel[radius=5,outer image radius=0.4,%
colors={"red","blue","magenta","purple","orange","green"}
]{"example-image-a","example-image-a","example-image-b","example-image-c"}{%
        A/10,
        B/10,
        C/10,
        D/10,
        E/10,
        F/10,
        G/10,
        H/10}
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Hmm, the text size of the smaller figure is not good. I think `\scalebox` is better

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,left=1.0cm,right=0.3cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,shadings}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set font to serif family
% smuggling from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470979/121799
\newcounter{smuggle}
\DeclareRobustCommand\smuggleone[1]{%
  \stepcounter{smuggle}%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname#1%
  \aftergroup\let\aftergroup#1\expandafter\aftergroup\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\smuggle[2][1]{%
  \smuggleone{#2}%
  \ifnum#1>1
    \aftergroup\smuggle\aftergroup[\expandafter\aftergroup\the\numexpr#1-1\aftergroup]\aftergroup#2%
  \fi
}
\begin{document}

    \scalebox{0.5}{\begin{tikzpicture}[
        % Environment Cfg
        font=\Large,
        scale=1,
        % Styles
    ]
\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,
radius/.initial=10,
outer image radius/.initial=0.5,
inner image radius/.initial=1,
outer image parameters/.initial={width=1.25cm},
inner image parameters/.initial={width=2.5cm},
Separator/.style={thick, color=black!50},
Border/.style={line width=1pt,color=red!60,shading=color wheel},
colors/.initial={}
}    
% lifeweel from many codes arround TEX.SE
%Variables: 1:images, 2:image 3:number of features 4: Feature_name/quantity
% 5: anchor aling 6: numbers position 7:Relative position 8:ID
\newcommand\LifeWeel[3][]{%
\def\imglst{{#2}}
\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,#1}
\edef\LstColors{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/colors}}
\edef\NumColors{0}
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 1] in \LstColors
{\edef\NumColors{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumColors}}
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {#2}
{\edef\NumImages{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumImages}}
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {#3}
{\edef\NumFeatures{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumFeatures}}
%Drawing the border
\draw[life wheel/Border] (0,0) circle [radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}];
%Drawing features separations.
\ifnum\NumColors>1
\foreach \m [count=\i] in {1,...,\NumFeatures}{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myi}{mod(\i-1,\NumColors)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\LstColors}[\myi]}
\draw[life wheel/Separator,top color=\mycolor!75!black,
bottom color=\mycolor,shading angle={-90+(360/\NumFeatures)*(\i-0.5)}] (0,0) -- (360/\NumFeatures*\i:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius})
arc({(360/\NumFeatures)*\i}:{(360/\NumFeatures)*(\i-1)}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius})
-- cycle;}
\else
\foreach \m [count=\i] in {0,1,...,\NumFeatures}{
\draw[life wheel/Separator] (0,0) -- (360/\NumFeatures*\i:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius});}
\fi

%Drawing the names
    \foreach \o/\p [count=\j] in {#3}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{ifthenelse(sin(360/\NumFeatures*\j)<0,-1,1)} 
        \ifnum\myint<0% True
        \path[%Reverse
            decoration={
                raise = -0.4ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center,
                reverse path
            },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/\NumFeatures*\j:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7) arc (360/\NumFeatures*\j:360/\NumFeatures*(\j-1):\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7);%\path
        \else%False
        \path[%Normal
            decoration={
                raise = -0.8ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center
                },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/\NumFeatures*\j:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.35) arc (360/\NumFeatures*\j:360/\NumFeatures*(\j-1):\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.35); %Path
        \fi
    \foreach \X in {1,...,\NumImages}
    {\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{360/\NumFeatures*\j+((1-2*\X)/(2*\NumImages))*360/\NumFeatures}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\imgname}{\imglst[\X]}
    \begin{scope}
     \clip (\tmp:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life
     wheel/radius}-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}}) 
     circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}];
     \node[rotate={\tmp-\myint*90}] at 
     (\tmp:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}})   
     {\edef\temp{\noexpand\includegraphics[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image parameters}]{\imgname}}
     \temp};    
    \end{scope}
    }
}
\begin{scope}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\imgname}{\imglst[0]}
    \clip (0,0) circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/inner image radius}];
    \node at (0,0)
    {\edef\temp{\noexpand\includegraphics[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/inner image parameters}]{\imgname}}
     \temp}; 
\end{scope}
}


% This function draws the lifeweel
%\LifeWeel{figures}{list of features in the form feature_name/quantity}
\LifeWeel[radius=5,outer image radius=0.4,%
colors={"red","blue","magenta","purple","orange","green"}
]{"example-image-a","example-image-a","example-image-b","example-image-c"}{%
        A/10,
        B/10,
        C/10,
        D/10,
        E/10,
        F/10,
        G/10,
        H/10}
        \end{tikzpicture}} \begin{tikzpicture}[
        % Environment Cfg
        font=\Large,
        scale=1,
        % Styles
    ]
\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,
radius/.initial=10,
outer image radius/.initial=0.5,
inner image radius/.initial=1,
outer image parameters/.initial={width=1.25cm},
inner image parameters/.initial={width=2.5cm},
Separator/.style={thick, color=black!50},
Border/.style={line width=1pt,color=red!60,shading=color wheel},
colors/.initial={}
}    
% lifeweel from many codes arround TEX.SE
%Variables: 1:images, 2:image 3:number of features 4: Feature_name/quantity
% 5: anchor aling 6: numbers position 7:Relative position 8:ID
\newcommand\LifeWeel[3][]{%
\def\imglst{{#2}}
\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,#1}
\edef\LstColors{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/colors}}
\edef\NumColors{0}
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 1] in \LstColors
{\edef\NumColors{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumColors}}
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {#2}
{\edef\NumImages{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumImages}}
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {#3}
{\edef\NumFeatures{\Y}
\smuggle[2]{\NumFeatures}}
%Drawing the border
\draw[life wheel/Border] (0,0) circle [radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}];
%Drawing features separations.
\ifnum\NumColors>1
\foreach \m [count=\i] in {1,...,\NumFeatures}{
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myi}{mod(\i-1,\NumColors)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\LstColors}[\myi]}
\draw[life wheel/Separator,top color=\mycolor!75!black,
bottom color=\mycolor,shading angle={-90+(360/\NumFeatures)*(\i-0.5)}] (0,0) -- (360/\NumFeatures*\i:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius})
arc({(360/\NumFeatures)*\i}:{(360/\NumFeatures)*(\i-1)}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius})
-- cycle;}
\else
\foreach \m [count=\i] in {0,1,...,\NumFeatures}{
\draw[life wheel/Separator] (0,0) -- (360/\NumFeatures*\i:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius});}
\fi

%Drawing the names
    \foreach \o/\p [count=\j] in {#3}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{ifthenelse(sin(360/\NumFeatures*\j)<0,-1,1)} 
        \ifnum\myint<0% True
        \path[%Reverse
            decoration={
                raise = -0.4ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center,
                reverse path
            },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/\NumFeatures*\j:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7) arc (360/\NumFeatures*\j:360/\NumFeatures*(\j-1):\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7);%\path
        \else%False
        \path[%Normal
            decoration={
                raise = -0.8ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center
                },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/\NumFeatures*\j:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.35) arc (360/\NumFeatures*\j:360/\NumFeatures*(\j-1):\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.35); %Path
        \fi
    \foreach \X in {1,...,\NumImages}
    {\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{360/\NumFeatures*\j+((1-2*\X)/(2*\NumImages))*360/\NumFeatures}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\imgname}{\imglst[\X]}
    \begin{scope}
     \clip (\tmp:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life
     wheel/radius}-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}}) 
     circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}];
     \node[rotate={\tmp-\myint*90}] at 
     (\tmp:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}})   
     {\edef\temp{\noexpand\includegraphics[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image parameters}]{\imgname}}
     \temp};    
    \end{scope}
    }
}
\begin{scope}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\imgname}{\imglst[0]}
    \clip (0,0) circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/inner image radius}];
    \node at (0,0)
    {\edef\temp{\noexpand\includegraphics[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/inner image parameters}]{\imgname}}
     \temp}; 
\end{scope}
}


% This function draws the lifeweel
%\LifeWeel{figures}{list of features in the form feature_name/quantity}
\LifeWeel[radius=5,outer image radius=0.4,%
colors={"red","blue","magenta","purple","orange","green"}
]{"example-image-a","example-image-a","example-image-b","example-image-c"}{%
        A/10,
        B/10,
        C/10,
        D/10,
        E/10,
        F/10,
        G/10,
        H/10}
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In case you need a macro

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,left=1.0cm,right=0.3cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,shadings}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set font to serif family
% smuggling from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470979/121799
\newcounter{smuggle}
\DeclareRobustCommand\smuggleone[1]{%
  \stepcounter{smuggle}%
  \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname#1%
  \aftergroup\let\aftergroup#1\expandafter\aftergroup\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\smuggle[2][1]{%
  \smuggleone{#2}%
  \ifnum#1>1
    \aftergroup\smuggle\aftergroup[\expandafter\aftergroup\the\numexpr#1-1\aftergroup]\aftergroup#2%
  \fi
}

\newcommand\LifeWeel[3][]{%
    \def\imglst{{#2}}
    \tikzset{life wheel/.cd,#1}
    \edef\LstColors{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/colors}}
    \edef\NumColors{0}
    \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 1] in \LstColors {%
        \edef\NumColors{\Y}
        \smuggle[2]{\NumColors}}
    \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {#2} {%
        \edef\NumImages{\Y}
        \smuggle[2]{\NumImages}}
    \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {#3} {%
        \edef\NumFeatures{\Y}
        \smuggle[2]{\NumFeatures}}
    %Drawing the border
    \draw[life wheel/Border] (0,0) circle [radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}];
    %Drawing features separations.
    \ifnum\NumColors>1
        \foreach \m [count=\i] in {1,...,\NumFeatures}{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myi}{mod(\i-1,\NumColors)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\LstColors}[\myi]}
            \draw[life wheel/Separator,top color=\mycolor!75!black,
                bottom color=\mycolor,shading angle={-90+(360/\NumFeatures)*(\i-0.5)}] (0,0) -- (360/\NumFeatures*\i:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius})
                arc({(360/\NumFeatures)*\i}:{(360/\NumFeatures)*(\i-1)}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius})
            -- cycle;}
    \else
        \foreach \m [count=\i] in {0,1,...,\NumFeatures}{
            \draw[life wheel/Separator] (0,0) -- (360/\NumFeatures*\i:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius});}
    \fi

%Drawing the names
    \foreach \o/\p [count=\j] in {#3}{
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myint}{ifthenelse(sin(360/\NumFeatures*\j)<0,-1,1)} 
        \ifnum\myint<0% True
        \path[%Reverse
            decoration={
                raise = -0.4ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center,
                reverse path
            },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/\NumFeatures*\j:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7) arc (360/\NumFeatures*\j:360/\NumFeatures*(\j-1):\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.7);%\path
        \else%False
        \path[%Normal
            decoration={
                raise = -0.8ex,
                text  along path,
                text = {|\huge|\o},
                text align = center
                },
            decorate
        ]
        (360/\NumFeatures*\j:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.35) arc (360/\NumFeatures*\j:360/\NumFeatures*(\j-1):\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}+0.35); %Path
        \fi
    \foreach \X in {1,...,\NumImages}
    {\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{360/\NumFeatures*\j+((1-2*\X)/(2*\NumImages))*360/\NumFeatures}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\imgname}{\imglst[\X]}
    \begin{scope}
     \clip (\tmp:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life
     wheel/radius}-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}}) 
     circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}];
     \node[rotate={\tmp-\myint*90}] at 
     (\tmp:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/radius}-1.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image radius}})   
     {\edef\temp{\noexpand\includegraphics[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/outer image parameters}]{\imgname}}
     \temp};    
    \end{scope}
    }
}
\begin{scope}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\imgname}{\imglst[0]}
    \clip (0,0) circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/inner image radius}];
    \node at (0,0)
    {\edef\temp{\noexpand\includegraphics[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/life wheel/inner image parameters}]{\imgname}}
     \temp}; 
\end{scope}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\yourcmd}[4]{%
    \scalebox{#1}{\begin{tikzpicture}[
        % Environment Cfg
        font=\Large,
        scale=1,
        % Styles
    ]
\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,
radius/.initial=10,
outer image radius/.initial=0.5,
inner image radius/.initial=1,
outer image parameters/.initial={width=1.25cm},
inner image parameters/.initial={width=2.5cm},
Separator/.style={thick, color=black!50},
Border/.style={line width=1pt,color=red!60,shading=color wheel},
colors/.initial={}
}    
\LifeWeel[#2]{#3}{#4}
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
\begin{document}

\yourcmd
    {0.5}
    {radius=5,outer image radius=0.4,colors={"red","blue","magenta","purple","orange","green"}}
    {"example-image-a","example-image-a","example-image-b","example-image-c"}
    {A/10,B/10,C/10,D/10,E/10,F/10,G/10,H/10}

\yourcmd
    {1}
    {radius=5,outer image radius=0.4,colors={"red","blue","magenta","purple","orange","green"}}
    {"example-image-a","example-image-a","example-image-b","example-image-c"}
    {A/10,B/10,C/10,D/10,E/10,F/10,G/10,H/10}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank so much. Can you edit and definition this wheel before begin{document} and in body you can call this definition and scale...if i copy and create 10 wheels in body so the code is very long,thanks

Comment: @latexforti See my edited answer.

Comment: The purpose of all that `\tikzset` stuff is precisely that you do not have to carry it around. You could (at least) simplify your command to `\newcommand{\yourcmd}[4]{%
    \scalebox{#1}{\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\Large,scale=1]
 \LifeWeel[#2]{#3}{#4}\end{tikzpicture}}
}` and say `\tikzset{life wheel/.cd,
...}` only once.