# How to epxand macro with optional argument equal to (x,y) so that it becomes part of \path(x,y)--(a,b); inside another macro (expansion problem)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, expansion

When `\myCoordinate` accepts MANDATORY argument, following works:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\myCoordinate[1]{#1}
\newcommand\myPath[1][(1,1)]{\path[draw=red]\myCoordinate{#1}--(1,0);}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\myPath
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But not when `\myCoordinate` accepts OPTIONAL argument (replace `\myCoordinate` and `\myPath` definitions from above with the following code):

```
% modify \myCoordinate to accept optional argument and set default value for that argument to (0,0)
\newcommand\myCoordinate[1][(0,0)]{#1}
% replace curly braces (for mandatory argument) with square brackets (for optional argument)
\newcommand\myPath[1][(1,1)]{\path[draw=red]\myCoordinate[#1]--(1,0);}
% you can replace \myPath definition with following one so that optional argument of \myCoordinate reverts to default (but it still doesn't work)
%\newcommand\myPath[1][(1,1)]{\path[draw=red]\myCoordinate--(1,0);}
```

Judging by the error generated (Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?), `tikz` is complaining because something is wrong with expansion of the macro. And that expansion problem is caused by the optional argument of `\myCoordinate`.

I need `\myCoordinate` to work while accepting single argument, which is optional argument. I need to make this work with as less complicated code as possible.

On a sidenote, to learn how to send values only to specific optional arguments out of all optional arguments that a command accepts, see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/490514/141768).

## Another approach fails alike.

When (instead of having `\myCoordinate` inside `\myPath`) `\myCoordinate` is passed to `\myPath` as an argument instead, it fails again when the argument of `\myCoordinate` is optional:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
% following \myCoordinate accepts optional argument and fails when passed as an argument to \myPath
\newcommand\myCoordinate[1][0,0]{#1}
\newcommand\myPath[1][(1,1)]{\path[draw=red]{#1}--(1,0);}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% neither of the two following lines work when \myCoordinate accepts optional argument
%\myPath[\myCoordinate] % fails
%\myPath[\myCoordinate[(0,0)]] % fails
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But when definition of `\myCoordinate` from above and the use of `\myPath` from above are changed to the following, it works again:

```
\newcommand\myCoordinate[1]{#1} % works
\myPath % works
%\myPath[\myCoordinate{(0,0)}] % works
```

So the optional-argument version of `\myCoordinate` can neither be used directly inside `\myPath` nor its value can be passed to `\myPath` as an argument.

## My comment on the [answer provided by @marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/490425/141768).

There is considerable downside of passing (pgf) key-value pairs as arguments to a path's style compared to `newcommand` or `NewDocumentCommand` (at least in the form showed in your answer, not sure if it can be corrected):

1. too long: compare `\myLine[1][north]` to `\path[myLine={subtract=1,anchor=north}]`, it's like referring to 3 separate commands at once (`\myLine`, `\subtract`, `\anchor`, or `\myLine[\subtract[1]][\anchor[north]]`)
2. because of this, renaming (if need be) of `subtract` and/or `anchor` will require replacement of each `subtract` and/or `anchor` occurrence in each `myLine` style which has parameters passed to it (and there may be tens or hundreds, if not more, in the entire document): compare to renaming `\subtract` and/or `\anchor` `newcommand`s which are used ONLY inside `\myLine` `newcommand` (in the document preamble)

If possible, solution should be (using value, not key-value, arguments---which relies on position or order of the values passed as arguments, not on their keys) the following: modify `tikzset` code to replace `\path[myLine={subtract=1,anchor=north}]` with something like `\path[myLine={1,north}]` where each of the arguments is optional (meaning that all of the following are valid and work as expected `\path[myLine]`, `\path[myLine={1}]`, and `\path[myLine={north}]`).

Comment: I'm not quite understanding.  I see how `\myL` has one optional parameter, and can be called by `\myL` or `\myL[south]`.  How does the other optional parameter fit in?  How do you intend to call `\myL`?

Comment: `\path[draw=red](\myN.#1 west)--(\myN.#1 east);`  makes no sense here because it doesn't use the second optional parameter #2 (default north)

Comment: I see in comments you've said you want to learn TeX macros from this question. There is a _lot_ wrapped up in `pgf`, and I'm really not sure this is the best way to learn low-level stuff. Certainly I'd stick to `pgf`'s own tools here.

Comment: A couple of notes on the concepts here. First, positional arguments get very unwieldy after a while: there's a reason that lots of packages have moved to keyvals. Second, renaming is something that if it's required can be handled in the preamble by setting the old key name as an equivalent to the new one. On the other hand, changing names in stable documents should be a last resort: ideally the input syntax should be stable. (And a good editor should normally help a lot if a rename is required.)

Comment: @bp2017 That would be a separate question, but I can see no reason for an error unless you are doing something like `/utils/exec = \ExplSyntaxOn \some_expl_code:\ExplSyntaxOff`, which will fail as tokenization has already occurred.

Comment: @JosephWright, I did `/utils/exec={\ExplSyntaxOn SOME_EXPL_CODE \ExplSyntaxOff}`. As soon as `SOME_EXPL_CODE` remains without on/off switches (which are placed outside), it works. I wonder why?

Comment: @bp2017 Covered in essence in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do: you have to change category codes _before_ you tokenize. You'd need `\ExplSyntaxOn\pgfkeys{/utils/exec = SOME_EXPL_CODE}\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea of pgf keys is precisely to avoid all this optional parameters and getting confused by them. Instead of rewriting all your commands and keeping in mind which parameter means what IMHO it is much simpler to use keys. In the example below, if you want to draw the path with all the default options, just do

```
\path[L];
```

If you want to subtract 1, have blue instead of red and south instead of north, do

```
\path[L={subtract=1,anchor=south,color=blue}];
```

You can reorder the keys as you want,

```
\draw[L={color=yellow,subtract=0,anchor=south}];
```

also works. Another advantage of this method is that it is downwards compatible, i.e. if you decide later that you need to add new keys the old commands will still work *without* the need of loading a new package.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\newcounter{myC}
\tikzset{L/.style={/utils/exec=\tikzset{bp/.cd,#1},insert path={[draw=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bp/color}] 
(\the\numexpr\number\value{myC}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bp/subtract}\relax.\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bp/anchor}\space west)
--(\the\numexpr\number\value{myC}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bp/subtract}\relax.\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bp/anchor}\space east)}},
bp/.cd,
subtract/.initial=0,
anchor/.initial=north,
color/.initial=red}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mystep/.code={\stepcounter{myC}}]
   \path node[draw,mystep](1)at (\number\value{myC},0){one};
   \path[L];
   \path node[draw,mystep](2)at (\number\value{myC},0){two};
   \path[L];
   \path[L={subtract=1,anchor=south,color=blue}];
   \draw[L={color=yellow,subtract=0,anchor=south}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `mystep` code is copied from [Andrew's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/490410/121799).

**ADDENDUM**: Reply to the comment in the question on my answer. It is possible to make something like `\path[myLine={north,1}];` work using key filters. However, in your case this would require more thoughts simply because a number is also a valid anchor. So how would Ti*k*Z know that `1` is not an anchor but the subtract key? (And personally I find it the suggestion not ver well thought, but of course there are well-thought versions of this, e.g. if you say `\node[circle,red,...` you do not have to say `shape=circle,color=red` because Ti*k*Z will figure this out for you. But in this case there is no ambiguity.)

Comment: +1 nice! I haven't seen `insert path` before.

Comment: Perhaps I should ask this as a "proper question", but is there any advantage to using `L/.style={/utils/exec=...}` over `L/.code={\tikzset{bp/.cd,#1}
    \path...}`? In this instance they seem to give the same result. Certainly, the latter is what I'd do "naturally".

Comment: @Andrew Yes, there are advantages. For instance, you can say ` \path[line width=1mm,L];`, you can combine such paths ` \path[L,L={subtract=1,anchor=south,color=blue}];`, give them names for intersections and many more.

Comment: @bp2017 Internally it is a macro-oriented approach, i.e. internally the pgf keys are macros.

Comment: @bp2017 The pgf keys can be used outside of Ti*k*Z. And you can definitely build them into `\newcommands`, it is just that in this very context I feel that `insert path` is advantageous. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481106/121799 for an example in which tons of pgf keys get used by a `\newcommand`.

Comment: @bp2017 Yes, sure. The problem may be though that, even though some things appear to be very basic, their implementation in LaTeX without packages is not, i.e. they may require tons of `\expandafter`s and so on. This is why there are packages that simplify these things for us by providing us with helpers. These helpers include `expl3`, `xparse` and IMHO also pgf keys. If you want to know how all the low-level magic works, have a look at TeX by topic (`texdoc texbytopic`).

Comment: @bp2017 Keys are higher level macros.

Comment: @bp2017 It does something. It switches to the subdirectory `bp`. All these options are stored in this subdirectory, and accessed e.g. with `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bp/subtract}`.

Comment: You can move `\tikzset` wherever you like, of course the styles have to be defined before you are using them, and you can use and switch to as many directories as you want.

Comment: If you are in a subdirectory, in order to switch in another one you need to say `/tikz/bp/.cd,`. It is like in ordinary directories in file systems.

Comment: Just a note on the code: Inside of a `\numexpr` you don't need to put `\the` or `\number` prior to `\value`, so `\the\numexpr\value{myC}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bp/subtract}\relax` does work.

Comment: @bp2017 Yes, these things can be addressed with the `search also` and `try` keys. However, I am not a fan of living or evolving questions. IMHO your original question was a well-defined question, and there are answers to it. You also got answers to your follow-up question. You would make things much better for all of us if you asked a new question. (Again, the answer is essentially in section **86.4.8 Handlers for Testing Keys** but because of my past experience I am not going to spell this out *here*.)

Comment: @bp2017 I do not understand your attitude. As you and everyone else can see I addressed at least 6 follow-up questions for you explicitly, and my answer is spelled out, it even has an explicit and working code.

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear to me what you are trying to do, but I don't think that you need two macros and that this following code might do want you want:

```
  \documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
  \usepackage{xparse}

  \newcounter{myC}
  \NewDocumentCommand{\myL}{O{north} O{0}}{%
    \def\myC{\the\numexpr(\themyC-#2)}
    \path[draw=red](\myC.#1 west)--(\myC.#1 east);
  }

  \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[mystep/.code={\stepcounter{myC}}]
        \path node[draw,mystep](1)at (\themyC,0){one};
        \myL
        \path node[draw,mystep](2)at (\themyC,0){two};
        \myL
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Note in particular the use of a `.code` statement to step the counter. I also added some coordinates for placing the nodes in the path statements since otherwise everything is drawn on top of each other.

Comment: I need `\newcommand` which you removed. I also use it for other means.

Comment: @bp2017 Just use `\newcommand\myN[1][0]{\the\numexpr(\value{myC}-#1)}`. I think that if you try to use `\myN` inside your `\myL` command then you will have expansion issues, which is part of why I did this the way that I did.

Comment: That's the problem: I need to solve the expansion issue.

Comment: Inside of \numexpr you shouldn't use \themyC but \value{myC}, \themyC might be redefined to output the value of myC as a Roman number or anything else.

Answer (score 4):

The way that `pgf` does parsing of it's arguments relies on an amount of 'look ahead' code, which takes the input and processes it one step at a time in order to extract possible actions. This is based on the idea that only a restricted range of material can appear in arbitrary positions inside a `pgf`/TikZ statement.

Here, looking for an optional argument involves an assignment (`\let`) which is not handled by the internals of `pgf`. At the TeX level, `\let` is not expandable so the two possible routes `pgf` has both fail: it's neither a known case nor something that can be expanded. The result would be an infinite loop, except `pgf` has a loop counter (set at 100 steps initially), which when exhausted leads to an alternative path giving the error.

As such, this is a fundamental limitation/design decision in how TikZ works. Other answers have tackled the problem in alternative ways, but you cannot use a macro with an optional argument here (at leas without trying to re-write significant parts of the TikZ parser).

Commands with only mandatory arguments do not *have* to have an assignment 'hidden' inside them, which is why they can work here. (Again, one would need to watch entirely arbitrary content.)

Comment: As far as I understand things you *can* install key filters in pgf and also use try such that Ti*k*Z could make sense out of `\path[myLine={1,north}]`. After all, this is how it makes sense of colors and so on. The problem though is that numbers are also valid anchors, so you cannot really come up with a sensible solution that also allows one to use numeric anchors at the same time. Other than that it is in principle possible to make something analogous to `\path[myLine={1,north}]` work *if* the OP provide a well-defined rule to discern them, which they don't.

Comment: @marmot Sure. I was looking at the core issue, and tried to find a way to make the 'TikZ expander' work here. But that is ultra-tricky: I think for an `expl3` version we'd use a scan token approach and more expandable code ..

Comment: I agree. My comment is just that Ti*k*Z does have means to "intelligently assign key values to keys", but of course this requires some effort. (My main concern is that I do not like evolving questions. The purpose of this site is IMHO not to serve one particular user, but many of them, so it is better to do things in steps IMHO.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `\myN`. Using its code directly in `\myL` will work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{myC}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myN[1][0]{\the\numexpr\themyC-#1\relax}
% square brackets now instead of curly braces
\def\myL{\@ifnextchar[\myL@i{\myL@i[0]}} 
\def\myL@i[#1]{\@ifnextchar[{\myL@ii[#1]}{\myL@ii[#1][north]}}
\def\myL@ii[#1][#2]{\path[draw=red](\the\numexpr\themyC-#1\relax.#2)--(1,0);}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node[draw,/utils/exec={\stepcounter{myC}}](1){one};
    \myL
    \path node[draw,/utils/exec={\stepcounter{myC}}](2){two};
    \myL[1][west]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, my code is only an example how it works. I have no idea what you really want to achieve ...

Comment: You have to be able to call `myN` from inside of `myL`. Which your answer does not do. Replace `\the\numexpr\themyC-#1\relax` with `\myN[#1]` (or anything that calls `myN` and passes an OPTIONAL argument to it).

Answer (score 1):

When `\myCoordinate` is used *inside* `\myPath` as in your initial code then there is no point in its having the capability to have an optional argument.  There is no code path starting from `\myPath` which does not pass a parameter to the inner `\myCoordinate`.  That is, there is no way to invoke `\myPath` such that the inner `\myCoordinate` falls back to its default argument.

Therefore, one option is to have an alternative command for the inner `\myCoordinate` which doesn't take an optional argument.  The user-level `\myCoordinate` can also use this alternative so there isn't duplication of code.

This would result in code like the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/490400/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\myCoordinate[1][(0,0)]{\myCoordinateAux{#1}}
\newcommand\myCoordinateAux[1]{#1}
\newcommand\myPath[1][(1,1)]{\path[draw=red]\myCoordinateAux{#1}--(1,0);}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\myPath
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You could use the usual `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` code to make the inner command inaccessible to users.

Comment: ". . . there is no way to invoke `\myPath` such that the inner `\myCoordinate` falls back to its default argument." But there is a way to invoke `\myCoordinate` in such a way (such that it falls back to its default argument) elsewhere, instead of writing yet another `\myCoordinate` (`\myCoordinateAux`). That's the point: code reuse (not code duplication).

Comment: @bp2017 as my code demonstrates, `\myCoordinate` is just a wrapper around `\myCoordinateAux`.  So there is no code duplication.  All `\myCoordinate` does is take its optional argument and pass it on to `\myCoordinateAux`.  All the important code is in `\myCoordinateAux`.