# Creating circular sectors of different radius at different angles

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, bar-chart, circles, arc

Tikz newbie here. How can I draw something like below in tikz. The angles/radius of each sector are fixed but the locations may change. Text/grid are not needed.
[image: Radial bar chart]

Here is what I have so far

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw circle (1cm);
\filldraw[fill=blue!40] 
     (320:1cm) -- (0,0) -- (220:1cm)
  arc[start angle=220, end angle=320, radius=1cm]
  -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=blue!40] 
     (0:1cm) -- (0,0) -- (-60:1cm)
  arc[start angle=0, end angle=-60, radius=1cm]
  -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get this
[image]

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/434564.

Answer (score 9):

Here is an automated version. Define a new command `\sectorfill` that takes a comma-separated list for input, where each entry has the form `<percentage>/<color>`. For example,

```
\sectorfill{25/blue,50/red,75/green,60/orange}
```

would create 4 sectors with radii given as percentages and respective colors. Any color that TikZ understands will work (for example, `green!40!black`).

The command:

```
\sectorfill{25/blue,50/red,75/green,60/orange,17/yellow,92/purple,47/brown,81/black,53/green!40!black}
```

creates the following image:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{nsect}
\newcommand{\sectorfill}[1]{\setcounter{nsect}{0}\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, gray]
    \foreach \i in {1,...,10}{\draw (0,0) circle[radius=\i];}
    \foreach [var=\r, var=\c] in {#1}{\addtocounter{nsect}{1}}
    \foreach [var=\r, var=\c, count=\n, evaluate=\n as \t using 360/\value{nsect}] in {#1}{
    \draw(0,0)--(\n*\t:10);
    \draw[fill=\c, opacity=.7](0,0)--(\n*\t:\r/10) arc(\n*\t:(\n-1)*\t:\r/10)--cycle;
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\sectorfill{25/blue,50/red,75/green,60/orange,17/yellow,92/purple,47/brown,81/black,53/green!40!black}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here a suggestion or more like a proof of concept of how to draw this in tikz.
with `\foreach` to draw the basic structure and `\filldraw` for colorization.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    
    %filling the cake
    \filldraw[opacity=0.5,fill=gray!10!white, draw=gray!10!white](0,0) -- (10mm,0mm) arc (0:360:10mm) -- cycle;
    \filldraw[fill=white, draw=white](0,0) -- (0.1mm,0mm) arc (0:360:0.1mm) -- cycle;
    
    \filldraw[opacity=0.5,fill=green!20!white, draw=none](0,0) -- (7mm,0mm) arc (0:45:7mm) -- cycle;    
    \filldraw[opacity=0.5,fill=red!20!white, draw=none](0,0) -- (6mm,0mm) arc (0:-45:6mm) -- cycle;
    
    \filldraw[opacity=0.5,fill=blue!20!white, draw=none](0,0) -- (-3mm,0mm) arc (0:-45:-3mm) -- cycle;
    \filldraw[opacity=0.5,fill=yellow!20!white, draw=none](0,0) -- (-8mm,0mm) arc (0:45:-8mm) -- cycle;
    
    \filldraw[opacity=0.5,fill=orange!20!white, draw=none] (0,0) -- (0,0.5) arc (90:45:0.5cm);
    \filldraw[opacity=0.5,fill=brown!20!white, draw=none] (0,0) -- (0,-0.5) arc (-90:-45:0.5cm);
    
    \filldraw[opacity=0.5,fill=black!20!white, draw=none] (0,0) -- (0,0.9) arc (90:135:0.9cm);
    \filldraw[opacity=0.5,fill=magenta!20!white, draw=none] (0,0) -- (0,-0.5) arc (-90:-135:0.5cm);


    
    %grid
    %rings
    \foreach \x in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1}
    \draw[line width=0.05mm,draw=white] (0,0) circle (\x cm);
    %lines
    \foreach \y in {0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315,360}    
    \draw[line width=0.05mm,draw=white] (0,0) -- (\y:1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Whithout grid:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The data are first stored in the macro `\WClist`. Here, the first value corresponds to the size and the second value to the color.

The gap between the slices is obtained with the key `gap`.

There are 2 wheelcharts. The first one draws the slices. Here the key `value=1` is used so that the angle of each slice is the same. The outer radius is given by the first variables in `\WClist`.

In the second wheelchart, the key `wheel data=Element \WCcount` is used. The macro `\WCcount` gives the current number of the slice. The rotation depends on the angle given by `\WCmidangle`. This is set in the key `wheel data style`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\sffamily
\def\WClist{%
  9/blue!50!black,
  6/blue,
  7/cyan,
  8/green,
  4/green!60!black,
  8/green!30!black,
  9/orange,
  7/orange!50!black,
  7/red,
  8/red!50!black%
}
\fill[gray!10] (0,0) circle[radius=11];
\wheelchart[
  data=,
  gap,
  radius={0}{\WCvarA},
  value=1
]{\WClist}
\wheelchart[
  data=,
  radius={10}{11},
  slices style={fill=none},
  value=1,
  wheel data=Element \WCcount,
  wheel data pos=0.5,
  wheel data style={
    darkgray,
    rotate={\WCmidangle<=180?\WCmidangle-90:\WCmidangle+90}
  }
]{\WClist}
\foreach\n in {1,...,11}{
  \draw[gray] (0,0) circle[radius=\n];
}
\foreach\n in {1,...,5}{
  \draw[gray] ({18+36*\n}:-11)--({18+36*\n}:11);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer. If you can come up with something clever, do share.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw circle (2cm);
\filldraw[fill=red!40] 
     (90:0.5cm) -- (0,0) -- (0:0.5cm)
  arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=0.5cm]
  -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=green!40] 
     (180:0.75cm) -- (0,0) -- (90:0.75cm)
  arc[start angle=90, end angle=180, radius=0.75cm]
  -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=blue!40] 
     (270:1cm) -- (0,0) -- (180:1cm)
  arc[start angle=180, end angle=270, radius=1cm]
  -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=yellow!40] 
     (360:1.5cm) -- (0,0) -- (270:1.5cm)
  arc[start angle=270, end angle=360, radius=1.5cm]
  -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is more like an edit of your MWE in your question rather than an answer.